# finding max value in each column and row

Tags: matlab

Say you have a 2D matrix,Is there a particular algorithm or way to do this in excel or matlab that would find the max of each row **and** column, such that each column and each row has only one maximal number N, where summing all N would result in the largest possible sum,i.e. is a row or column has a max number that is repeated.,  as such with the simple example below

```
1 2 4          
3 1 4         
1 2 4
```

the out put would be

1 2 **4**

**3** 2 4

1 **2** 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the maximum bipartite matching in a (complete) graph, where your matrix represents the edge weights matrix. You can compute this value using the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) (MATLAB implementation available for [download from File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11609-hungarian-algorithm)). Since you want the maximum match, negate all the numbers in your matrix and feed it to this function. You will get back two outputs - one is the (negative of) the maximum sum and the other a binary matrix with ones where the maximal elements occur in each row and column and zeros everywhere else.